# Utility to flip all pages in a PDF

Tags: pdf, documents, print-to-pdf, flip

I have a PDF file (generated using the Save As PDF function in MS Word 2007) where I would like to flip all pages in the document (rotate 180 degrees - so that they will be upside down). I do not have Adobe Acrobat Writer. Can someone recommend a free tool that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PDFTK Builder](http://www.angusj.com/pdftkb/)   is a free graphical interface to the Windows version of PDFTK making it much easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

Simply rotate it in Acrobat Reader options and print (I'm assuming you meant you don't have Acrobat **Writer**, not Reader). You can use [**CutePDF**](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/Writer.asp) to print it to a PDF.

Comment: Changed to specify Writer in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [PDFCreator](http://en.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) for years now. It installs a printer driver that you can print to from Acrobat Reader or whatever program you want.

Comment: As a side note: such printer drivers won't create clickable indexes and links. Whenever you can save as PDF from an application directly, that's probably preferred.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFill Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdftool_rotate_crop.html) can do this and its free. It is a very handy program to keep around for all kinds of pdf operations like this.